# PHP IF (a=b) do nothing ELSE do something

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, mysqli

This code below displays a companys legal name in H1 (works) then it should if the cust_details_name is not equal to cust_details_legal display the companies trading name (doesn't work).

Both fields have sample data that is diffrent "Nike" in one and "Addidas" in the other.

There are no error messages.  I have put an echo in the first part of the if and this returns a statement.  So as far as I can tell the statement is returning true when in fact it should return false and use the else statement.  **Any suggestions?, thanks in advance!**

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);
echo "<h1>" . strtoupper($row['cust_details_legal']) . "</h1>";
if ($row['cust_details_name'] == $row['cust_details_legal'])
{ }
else
{
echo "<p><small>Trading As<em>" . $row['cust_details_name'] . "</em></small></p>";
}
```

Comment: Is your `error_reporting` `on`? Simply place `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` into next line after `<?php`

Comment: Try to use `$row[0]['cust_details_name'] == $row[0]['cust_details_legal']`. As I believe, it returns an array of all the rows, each containing the details you need. If I am wrong, please someone let me know.

Comment: Also, you are using `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)`, why are you mixing mysql and mysqli? Use `MYSQLI_ASSOC`

Comment: Is it just me, or would it be simpler to do `if ($row['cust_details_name'] !== $row['cust_details_legal'])`...

Comment: Thanks for the comments - advice taken on board :)

Answer (score 0):

Cleaered cache on testing server and this got it working.  Frazzeled my brain!